# Importing category meta description

Tags: import, magento-1.9

Is there a way to import the meta description for categories?

I am on version 1.9 of the community edition and use the Magmi importer tool.

Comment: Is solved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an extension for the import. Unfortunately it does cost money.

Here is the link: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-category-import-export.html